# Does high cpu load make apache reject incoming requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, central-processing-unit, mariadb

I am deploying a laravel app on a RHEL7.x server with apache as the underlyiing web server. Part of the functionality of the application is to accept http POST requests from other servers and save their details to the app's mariadb database.

My problem is that sometimes it seems like the server is rejecting some incoming messages without any trace in apache's access or error logs. I can see from the other server's end that the request has been sent but it seems to never have hit the server or at least the server doesn't log the messages as having been recieved.

I suspect this behaviour is caused by the fact that my app runs a rather cpu-intensive set of mysql queries every two minutes. This makes the servers resource usage peek for about 20 seconds at a time. Am I right in suspecting that the high resource usage could be the reason for apache not responding to requests? Are there any mechanisms or configuration options that would allow me to specify a "waiting time"  or queue of sorts that would allow apache to process the requests after the system load has settled?

Comment: Apache can either spawn a child, or (if all children are busy) queue up the request.  Increase the queue length.  (Sorry, I don't have the details.)

Comment: Also check your mariadb status `show global status`. If its run out of table open cache slots it could result in requests just waiting for a cache slot to open the table again. You'll need to check if your are cpu exhausted, or are apache/mariadb going into swap because of memory exhaustion (so more memory or restricted memory tuning).